# Python regex, pattern-match multiple backslash characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a python raw string, that has five backslash characters followed by a double quote. I am trying to pattern-match using python `re`.

The output must print the  matching pattern. In addition, two characters before/after the pattern.

```
import re
command = r'abc\\\\\"abc'
search_string = '.{2}\\\\\\\\\\".{2}'
pattern = re.compile(search_string)
ts_name = pattern.findall(command)
print ts_name
```

The output shows,

```
['\\\\\\\\"ab']
```

I expected

```
['bc\\\\\"ab']
```

Anomalies:

1) Extra characters at the front - `ab` are missing

2) Magically, it prints eight backslashes when the input string contains just five backslashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify (shorten) your regex and use `search` function to get your output:

```
command = r'abc\\\\\"abc'
search_string = r'.{2}(?:\\){5}".{2}'
print re.compile(search_string).search(command).group()
```

**Output:**

```
bc\\\\\"ab
```

Your regex should also use `r` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

just add a capturing group around the part you want:

```
command = r'a(bc\\\\\"ab)c'
```

and access it with:

```
match.group(1)
```